# Como solucionar el error hresult e_fail de una llamada a un componente com?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Buen dia compañeros,

Me ha surgido este error al querer agregar una referencia, me podrían ayudar, se que este problema es muy general pero si tienen la solución me podrían ayudar?
Este error me surge en el visual studio 2017
[image: HRESULTE_FAIL]

saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente encontré la respuesta en este link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260196/add-a-reference-raise-error-error-hresult-e-fail-h.html

1. Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin
2. CD into `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"`
3. Run `gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll`

After a restart, it all worked well.